# Java Servlet to generate an an m by n multiplication table based on user input

Tags: java, html, servlets, html-table, multiplication

Beginner question.  I have a basic html form with one user input text box labelled "Enter a number" and a submit button labelled "Create a multiplication table".  This is the working  with a servlet to display an html formatted multiplication table.  Everything else is working fine just the formatting is off; I can't seem to get the top row and far left column to number properly.  It should look like this:

[image: the x's represent the products]

Instead it looks like this (the input number was 7 in this example):

[image]

My servlet code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Main")
public class Main extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements
    javax.servlet.Servlet {
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Main() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException    {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String title = "Multiplication Table";
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>" + title + "</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body");

    out.println("<center>");
    out.println("<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=70%>");

    try {
        int op = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("op"));
        if (op > 10) {
            out.println("<h1>Enter a number between 1 and 10!</h1>");

        } else if (op < 10) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= op; i++) {

                out.println("<tr>");
                for (int j = 1; j <= op; j++) {

                    out.println("<td>" + i * j + "</td>");
                }
                out.println("</tr>");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        out.println("<body><h1>Enter numbers only!</h1></body>");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. For one you probably shouldn't embed HTML in a Servlet, also you should try and validate your HTML - you would have found a few issues.

You didn't close your `<body` tag.

You aren't closing your `<table>` tag.

You are calling `System.out.println()` and you probably meant `out.println();` Also, you might be embedding your header in the table.

```
out.println("<body>"); <-- added `>`
out.println("<center>");
try {
    int op = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("op"));
    if (op > 10) {
        out.println("<h1>Enter a number between 1 and 10!</h1>");
    } else if (op < 10) {
        out.println("<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=70%>");
        for (int i = 1; i <= op; i++) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            for (int j = 1; j <= op; j++) {
                // EDIT
                if (i == 1 || j == 1) {
                  out.println("<td align='right'>" + i * j + "</td>");
                  // out.println("<td style='text-align: right'>" + i * j + "</td>");
                } else {
                  out.println("<td>" + i * j + "</td>");
                }
                // END EDIT
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println(); <-- out.println() - not System.out.println();
        }
        out.println("</table>"); // <-- close the table tag.
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    out.println("<h1>Enter numbers only!</h1>"); // <-- no <body>
}
out.println("</center>\n</body>"); <-- close center and body.
```

Comment: Corrected those errors and it's still  not displaying correctly.   Thank you for catching those though, my eyes are crossing.

Comment: Now that you have proper HTML code you may want to add `CSS` to set the style of the cells

Comment: @user2948381 Edited to include requested text alignment. Based on your example, you should set the right alignment when `i == 1` or `j == 1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the CSS `first-child` property. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/gqCSn/)

Comment: Well the best solution to align things in an HTML table is CSS, that's why I've posted that fiddle that contains the appropriate CSS. IMO this is not even a Java question